# React TagsInput not working with backspace key after pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, input, react-redux

I have defined a TagsInput in react

```
<TagsInput value={breadcrumbs}
onChange={this.onChange}
inputProps={{onChange:this.inputChange, value: this.state.query}} />

//onChange method is called when enter is pressed
onChange() {
 const q = this.state.query;
 const url = this.state.url;
 this.props.actions.reduxPushState(null, url);
}

//inputChange is called on every change in search bar query
inputChange(e) {
 const query = event.target.value;
 this.setState({ query });
 // logic to build url
 let url;

 this.setState({ url });
}
```

Here in input if I type something (eg `query` is "home") and press enter `onChange` is called with `query` equals "home". Now if i press <kbd>backspace</kbd>, `onChange` is called instead of `inputChange` which is a strange behaviour. Can anyone explain why `onChange` is called when backspace is pressed?